# How many places can app store data

Tags: root-access

I have an application and I want to swipe all data after uninstalling. I have followed those steps:

1. remove applications
2. remove all app's data in `/sdcard/`. I have this information based on some tracking apps on market such as `SDMaid`
3. remove all cookies.

Here is the code for remove cookies app:

```
public static void clearCookies(Context context) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Using clearCookies code for API >=" + String.valueOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1));
        CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
        CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Using clearCookies code for API <" + String.valueOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1));
        CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
        cookieSyncMngr.startSync();
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
        cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
        cookieSyncMngr.stopSync();
        cookieSyncMngr.sync();
    }
}
```

But when I install again, application still remember who I am. (I don't log in, I just anonymous add some products to cart). I also reset OS and see that everytime I reset, application will load again from fresh state so it means application doesn't store any my private information such as device id ...

My question is: where can an application can store data. I have researched and cannot find more.

thanks

Comment: The application might be using Android ID which is recommended for identifying a device/user. That ID is changed with every factory reset. To confirm that this ID is used by that app, completely remove the app, change the android_id using adb, install the app and let us know the result.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have tested this situation too. I have faked many datas including android id, imei, android advertising id ... using this app (pro version): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phoneinfo.changer. but still gain no result.

Comment: I think maybe data can be saved to somewhere else. (such as WebSetting, keystore, cookie ...). Anything that outside of an application scope itself. But  I cannot pointed out.

Comment: Can you mention the name or link of that particular app?

Comment: I tested on AliExpress.https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alibaba.aliexpresshd 
The folder I detected and tried to delete is: 
1. `sdcard/.DataStorage` 2. `sdcard/.com.taobao.dp` 3. `sdcard/.UTSystemConfig`

Comment: I also updated code for remove cookie for my question. Step following is: when first installing, app will have popup ask to choose some category. and then I add some products to cart. (we will see total number items on top if we success). And then I remove app and clear all stuffs as I discuss above, install again, still appear same items in cart.

Comment: I think you should clear cache of Google Play Service and Google Play Service platform also.

Comment: thanks. I have tried but gaining no result. I have intercepted requests from my device. I see one request send to server with string `client-id`. The value doesn't look like any thing I have changed. Are there any thing related to this value that app can recognize my identity? I have googled but found no result about `android-id`. thanks

Comment: @Firelord do you have a way for dealing with this problem ? thanks.

Comment: No way known to me as of now.